# Visual Metaphor for Inversion

Tags: user-interface

Before you throw me out into the cold with your bold assertions that this is not programming related, please hear me out.

I'm looking for a visual metaphor (Icon) to suggest the idea of inversion of a filter.  So if a user has a filter which reduces a list of 10 items to 4, I want a button that will allow the user to invert the filter to display only the other 6.

Another wrinkle is that the UI will also have a button for removing the filter nearby.

While this certainly isn't a nuts-and-bolts programming question, I think it's relevant to the process of software creation.  As a developer it's relatively easy to construct the mechanisms to perform complex filters, but it's all for naught if normal users find the presentation confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an icon doesn't jump to mind for you, then there probably isn't one that will have obvious meaning to your users either. You're better off using a text label for this.

If it *must* be an icon, then it doesn't matter much what it is, since users won't be able to guess it any way, but at least try to make it visually distinct and memorable if not particularly intuitive. MS Access uses a funnel to represent "filtering." Maybe use an upside-down or white-on-black funnel for inversion? (An X'ed-out funnel means "don't filter").

Whatever. Like I said, it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's *not* the most appropriate, but what about the [logical inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_%28logic_gate)) icon?

Comment: I like the idea.  Not sure my users are that geeky.

Comment: I agree but users can learn fairly quickly the meanings of icons. Don't underestimate the power of *icons* :-)

Comment: In that case, you may as well make it a green hippopotamus.
The idea is to make it obvious on first (or any) viewing, and logic gate symbols don't have good metaphors that extend beyond silicon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:  <kbd>Invert Selection</kbd>?

If you really need an image, I'd suggest looking at image editing programs like GIMP or Photoshop and seeing how their "invert selection" buttons look.

Comment: Have they got buttons (with icons) for that?  I'm not a GIMP guy, but in Photoshop I'm only aware of the menu item.

Comment: Sure seems like I've seen it somewhere... I'm picturing like, a square with a corner taken out.

Answer (score 0):

16x16 pixels is enough to draw two small list boxes with an arced arrow going from one to the other where the second has an inverted selection list of the first.

Answer (score 0):

[alt text http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/6782/4092009000139am.png](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/6782/4092009000139am.png)

I think the 3 icons above could be used in one spot with each user click causing a rotation through the 3 of them. I think the above icon set offers the following benefits:

1. F - clearly communicates it is for a filter control.
2. Red and Green - clearly communicate ON and OFF action.
3. The line above F means inversion (I think - based on memories of boolean algebra at university - I could be wrong?)
4. The use of yellow while still maintaining the F, links the new action (filter inverted) to the previous filter actions let still communicates it is different to the filter simply being turned on or off.
5. On icon click rotation could be, (starting) Red - Green - Yellow - Red. This is a widely understood rotation pattern that the user would quickly pick-up. Therefore no need for additional filter on/off button.
6. Simpler solution - a user only needs to look at a single icon (even perhaps only with peripheral vision) to deduce the current state of the control.

Comment: Good effort.  In my particular case I need is an icon to suggest the verb "invert this" rather than just the state "this is inverted."